# Rules for derivatives of a composition

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, partial-derivative

Assume $\varphi: [0,1] \rightarrow [0, \infty)$ is continuous, strictly decreasing function.

In the book ([1], p. 91) it is claimed that

\begin{align}
& \int_0^1 \int_0^1 \varphi(\varphi^{-1}(u)+\varphi^{-1}(v)) ~d(\varphi(\varphi^{-1}(u)+\varphi^{-1}(v))) \\[10pt]
= {} & \int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1} \varphi(\varphi^{-1}(u)+\varphi^{-1}(v)) \cdot \varphi''(\varphi^{-1}(u)+\varphi^{-1}(v)) \cdot  [ \varphi' \circ \varphi^{-1}(u)]^{-1} \cdot  [ \varphi' \circ \varphi^{-1}(v)]^{-1} \, du \, dv
\end{align}

How do we get this result? What are the intermediate steps that were skipped here, if any? If not, what is the general rule for derivation that was used here?

[1]: *Joe, Harry*, Multivariate models and dependence concepts, Monographs on Statistics and Applied Probability. 73. London: Chapman and Hall. xviii, 399 p. (1997). [ZBL0990.62517](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0990.62517).

Answer (score 0):

My attempt is giving me a different answer.
Using chain rule gives $$d(\varphi(\varphi^{-1}(u)+\varphi^{-1}(v)))=\varphi'(\varphi^{-1}(u)+\varphi^{-1}(v))~d(\varphi^{-1}(u)+\varphi^{-1}(v))=\varphi'(\varphi^{-1}(u)+\varphi^{-1}(v)) ~[\varphi' \circ \varphi^{-1}(u))^{-1} + (\varphi' \circ \varphi^{-1}(v))^{-1}] \, du \, dv$$

Perhaps someone can correct me.

Comment: Thank you for your input! In the later book by Joe I found a cleaner proof of the same theorem while avoiding this differential, however, no indication so far that the former was incorrect (i.e., no mentions in the errata or anything).